# React deploy i18n

Tags: reactjs, build, i18n

У меня после deploy, языки слетели, но когда в package.json файле удаляю "homepage" - все снова работает... как решить проблему?

Языки добавил с помощью i18n и кстати этот файл не добавился в build папку... в ручную добавил - но не помог

Вроде мне нужно изменить адресс языкогого обеспечения от локального к gh-page адрессу, помогите плиз

```
 backend: {
            /* translation file path */
            loadPath: '/assets/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'
        },
```

Comment: вы используете библиотеку `react-i18next`?

Comment: react-i18n ... это одно и тоже i18next? по-моему да

Comment: Как такого, в вашем вопросе нету упоминания библиотек. i18n - Локализа́ция програ́ммного обеспече́ния.

Comment: код добавил, надеюсь помогут как нить

Comment: судя по загружаемой папке, вам следует проверить, то что файлы корректно создаются в папке `build`. Маршрут для них примерно `build/asserts/i18n....`

Comment: + папка `assets` в вашем проекте должна быть в папке `public`

Comment: да, эти файлы в папке assets норм добавляються, но в build не добавилься i18n.js файл

Comment: в проекте  в паблике и  работает все, только в gh-pages не работает

Comment: Честно, сложно тогда сказать что является корнем проблемы... Как вариант,  это  пройтись по гайду на  официальном сайте еще раз. Другой вариант, это проверить импорт `i18n.js` в `index.js`... 3 вариант - наклепать проект в codesandbox.io и последний - написать в обычном SO. Там разработчики вам ответят быстро

Comment: Спасибо, надеюсь смогу решить как-то, спасибо за потраченое время